# Стили компонента битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Использую компонент "битрикс веб форм". Попытался скопировать шаблон компонента в свой шаблон сайта и попробовать там менять стили, ничего не изменилось. Где можно хранить стили данного компонента? (не хочу хранить их в стилях сайта)

Answer (score 1):

/bitrix/temlates/*Название шаблона сайта*/components/bitrix/*название компонента*/*название шаблона*/

Стили должны лежать в папке используемого шаблона компонента и файл называться styles.css

Comment: В том то и дело что он есть но в стилях меняю и ничего не происходит..
http://prntscr.com/ca3yh8

Comment: Сбросьте кэш браузера